# iPhone xcode build fail - file unfound

Tags: xcode, build, lexical

I was downloading wikihow open source code for iPhone - to local xcode to run and view.

https://github.com/keishi/wikihow-iphone-app

After download, when i build and run it, it fail.

Error as:

1- No such file or directory, WHNetworkAlertView.h

However, the file is exist at

```
/Classes/Views/WHNetworkAlertView.h
/Classes/Views/WHNetworkAlertView.m
```

This file is calling from wikiHowAppDelegate.m as #import 'WHNetworkAlertView.h'

2- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'WHNetworkAlertView.h' file not found

3- '*' undecleared (first use in this function)
WHNetworkAlertView undeclared

When I navigate to the file via xcode to view, xcode unable to open it...

Any idea how to fix?

---

Second question:

I heard we can request Apple to give a go live test before the actual release to app store. BUT

After using xcode to build iphone app, do I able to usb the file to real iphone for testing purpose? instead of just using the simulator (sometimes actual environment might have some different issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of unmaintained opensource projects that don't build.

The locations of four files are wrong in the project. It's easy to fix.

1. Open the `Classes/Views` subtree in the xcode sidebar.
2. See those 4 red files? Select them
3. Right click on them and select `Get Info`
4. Click the `Choose...` button next to path
5. Navigate to the `Classes/Views` folder in the file panel and select `Choose`
6. Filenames should be black now, try to build.

---

> After using xcode to build iphone app, do I able to usb the file to real iphone for testing purpose? instead of just using the simulator (sometimes actual environment might have some different issue)

You can do this if you are a member of the ios developer program. I.E. after you have paid them $99.

Comment: Here come another error:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/alex/Desktop/IPHONE/Open source/keishi-

wikihow-iphone-app-37bd0f1/Classes/Libraries/FlurryLibWithLocation'
Undefined symbols for architecture 

i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in wikiHowAppDelegate.o
ld: 

symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I search through all files, no such wording (FlurryLibWithLocation) appear in the project.
I click on tree view and refer to 

Classes/Libraries/FlurryLib, no red color, all files pointed to the right location path.  Any idea?

Comment: remove `[FlurryAPI startSession:FLURRY_API_KEY];`

Comment: :) thanks for the reply. I finally getting more familiar with Apple. Recently change from windows to apple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to locate the missing (red) files using the new Xcode 4 interface: 1) select the file or files in the left hand Project Navigator (the folder icon); 2. In the right sidebar click on "File Inspector" which is the leftmost icon resembling a page; 3. In the "Identity and Type" section, there is a grey box labeled "Location". Click on the small icon to the lower left that resembles a file browser - this will come up with a file browser to locate the file. Voila, you are done.